# When is reversion just a conjugaison by $z \mapsto iz$ or by $z \mapsto -z$?

Tags: power-series, inverse-function

The origin of the question is the computation of two integrals
$$F(x) = \int_0^x \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\cos(y)} \textrm{ for } |x|<\pi/2,$$
$$\tilde F(x) = \int_0^x \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\cosh(y)} \textrm{ for } x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
Classical formulae yield
$$F(x) = \ln \tan \Big(\frac{x}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\Big),$$
$$\tilde{F}(x) = 2\arctan(e^x)-\frac{\pi}{2} = 2\Big(\arctan(e^x)-\frac{\pi}{4}\Big).$$
What is surprising is that $\tilde{F}$ is the inverse bijection of $F$!

At the same time, the functions $F$ and $\tilde{F}$ can be extended into holomorphic functions, at least on the simply connected open sets $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |\Re(z)| < \pi/2\}$ and $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |\Im(z)| < \pi/2\}$. And because of the relation $\cosh(z) = \cos(iz)$ (and vice-versa), these two functions are related by $\tilde{F}(z) = F(iz)/i$.

How one can « explain » this coincidence? Do we have other non-trivial examples?

Alternative formulas for $F$ and $\tilde{F}$ give us a hint:
$$F(x) = \ln \frac{1+\tan(\frac{x}{2})}{1-\tan(\frac{x}{2})} = 2 \arg\tanh \tan(x/2),$$
$$\tilde{F}(x) = 2\arctan\Big(\frac{e^x-1}{e^x+1}\Big) = 2\arctan \tanh(x/2).$$
Now, we see why $\tilde{F}$ is at the same time the inverse bijection of $F$ and given by $\tilde{F}(z) = F(iz)/i$.

And we know how to construct other examples. Indeed, set $H(z)=iz$. Let $G$ be any holomorphic function defined on an open set containing $0$ such that $G(0)=0$ and $G'(0) \ne 0$. Hence (by local inversion theorem for holomorphic functions) the function $G$ can be reversed on the neighborhood of $0$. Assume that the first non-zero Since $G$ and $H^2$ commute, the function $F := G \circ H \circ G^{-1} \circ H^{-1}$ satisfies
$$F^{-1} = H \circ G \circ H^{-1} \circ G^{-1} = H^{-1} \circ G \circ H \circ G^{-1} = H^{-1} \circ F \circ H.$$

**Question:** Does this method provide all power series such that $f(z) \sim z $ as $z \to 0$ and whose local inverse (for the composition law $\circ$ ) is given by $\tilde{F}(z) = F(iz)/i$?

We get a slightly simpler variant of this question by replacing $H$ by the map $z \mapsto -z$ and by removing the assumption $G$ is odd.

Let us give an example : set $G(z) = z+z^2$, so $G^{-1}(z) = \frac12(-1+\sqrt{1+4z})$ at the neighborhood of $0$, where $\sqrt{}$ is the principal determination of the square root on $\mathbf{C} \setminus \mathbf{R_-}$. Then we get
$$F(z) = G \big(-G^{-1}(-z) \big) = 1-z-\sqrt{1-4z},$$
$$F^{-1}(z) = -G \big(-G^{-1}(z) \big) = 1-z+\sqrt{1+4z}$$

Comment: Those formulas can be written even more simply as $\tanh^{-1}(\sin(x))$ and $\sin^{-1}(\tanh(x))$

Comment: Or perhaps even better, $\cos^{-1}(\operatorname{sech}(x))$ and $\operatorname{sech}^{-1}(\cos(x))$.